# Angular drag n drop: Splice not a function on three level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-dragdrop

I'm currently implementing a menu editor. I have the problem, that the first level of elements is perfectly draggable, the levels two and three only return errors about splice or eval not being a function. 
Dragging works, but the inserting fails.

```
"Error: scope.$eval(...).splice is not a function"
```

http://codepen.io/merlin-schumacher/pen/VaZWEe

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

There now exists a solution for adding own behaviour when insertions take place adding more flexibility:

> From 1.4.0 you can now return true in dnd-drop to tell the directive that you will take care of the insertion yourself.

For more details see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/issues/86#issuecomment-181134983)